# convert digit number to n digit string with gsub in lua

Tags: string, lua, number-formatting, digits

I have a function that return a string. Inside that function, a table with multiple variable (number or string type).

Something like this:

```lua
function myfunction(format)
-- do something

myTable={}
myTable["a"] = "HelloWord"
myTable["b"] = number1 -- range between (0-500)
myTable["c"] = number2 -- range between (0-50)

local outputString = format:gsub("%%(%a+)", myTable)
return outputString
end
```

Output of this function is something like this

```lua
myfunction("%a-%b-%c")
HelloWord-3-9
```

I need something like this

```lua
myfunction("%a-%b-%c")
HelloWord-003-09
```

I prefer to do this in line

```lua
local outputString = format:gsub("%%(%a+)", myTable)
```

not store `b` and `c` as string, I am not sure if it is possible or not?

Update: if I use

```
myTable["b"] = string.format("%0.3i", number1) -- range between (0-500)
myTable["c"] = string.format("%0.2i", number2) -- range between (0-50)
```

then I should store that as string not number.

Comment: You can use `string.format`

Comment: If I use something like this `string.format("%0.3i", number1)` than I store data as string but I want to save that as number just in last step print that as string

Comment: You said finally you need a string, why did you want to save as number?

Comment: @JACK maybe @shingo mean that you can do most things directly in ```format()``` ? - Than try: ```function myFunction(format) local myTable = {a = "HelloWorld", b = 500, c = 50} return(format:format(myTable.a, math.random(myTable.b), math.random(myTable.c))) end myFunction("%s-%d-%d")``` - And return it.

Comment: Example - Returning the numbers as floating points: ```print(myFunction('%s-%f-%f'))``` - Give out the string: ```HelloWorld-343.000000-25.000000```